# Is there a Kotlin function to split a string into an array?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, split

I have tried str.split(,).toTypedArray(), but it doesn’t make an array.

```
var tasks = ""

tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")

val array = tasks.split(",").toTypedArray()

array.forEach {println(it)}
```

the output returns nothing so far.

Is there a way to split the string where the input is:

`"xyx yxy xyx"`
 and get an output:
`["xyx","yxy","xyx"]`

Comment: [Yes](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin strings are immutable, so don't expect this:

```
tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
```

to append anything to `tasks`.
The operator function `plus()` returns the string that you want to append but does not also append it.
You must do it like this:

```
tasks = tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
tasks = tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
tasks = tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
tasks = tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
```

and then with:

```
val array = tasks.split(",").toTypedArray()
array.forEach { println(it) }
```

the result that will be printed is:

```
<empty line here because of the 1st comma>
Hey
Hey
Hey
Hey
```

Comment: Though if you're going to construct a string, calling `plus()` is a very inefficient way of doing it.  (It will create ever-longer temporary copies.)  Far better to append everything to a StringBuilder, and then convert that to a String at the end.

Comment: @gidds I aggree with you. My answer is not about the efficiency of the method but why *it does not work* as the OP says.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't criticising your answer, which is good!  I was just adding a further point about the code (as it's something people tend to get wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on the `space` char using `split` which returns a `List` then call `toTypedArray` to produce an `array` from that list.

```
val arr = "xyx yxy xyx".split(" ").toTypedArray();
```

Here's an online [Demo](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjQxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5pbXBvcnQgamF2YS51dGlsLkFycmF5c1xuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFsIGFyciA9IFwieHl4IHl4eSB4eXhcIi5zcGxpdChcIiBcIikudG9UeXBlZEFycmF5KCk7XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihBcnJheXMudG9TdHJpbmcoYXJyKSk7XG59In0=).

Answer (score 0):

`tasks` in your code remains empty, the following works as expected:

```
var tasks = ""

tasks = tasks.plus(",").plus("Hey")
.plus(",").plus("Hey")
.plus(",").plus("Hey")
.plus(",").plus("Hey")

val array = tasks.split(",").toTypedArray()
```

You can actually have have `tasks` as `val` like so:

```
val tasks = ",".plus("Hey")
.plus(",").plus("Hey")
.plus(",").plus("Hey")
.plus(",").plus("Hey")
```

or even

```
val tasks = ",Hey,Hey,Hey,Hey"
```

and also

```
",Hey,Hey,Hey,Hey".split(",").forEach { println(it) }
```